# flex 3 : sorting date column in datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3

How to sort date column in datagrid with date format of 'DD/MM/YY'? Please give me sample.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a sortCompareFunction for your datagrid column. For example,  http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/12/sorting-date-columns-in-a-datagrid/